# Extract data passing through operator IMAGE_OT_sample in Python

Tags: python, blender, sample, image-editor

During preview image in UV/Image editor, I can click a right mouse button, then in bottom corner appears information about coordinate(X, Y) and color(R, G, B) pressed pixel. How can I get this information(coordinate, color) in Python?

I found in source IMAGE_OT_sample
https://github.com/martijnberger/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/space_image/image_ops.c#L2996

and

```
static void image_sample_apply(bContext *C, wmOperator *op, const wmEvent *event)
```

But I don't have an idea how to extract this data in Python.

[image]

Comment: I think extract information it's impossible but context provides all information to calculate coordinate and color. I use something like this: 

    w, h = list(context.edit_image.size)
    fx, fy = context.region.view2d.region_to_view(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
    coordinate_x, coordinate_y = int(fx * w), int(fy * h)
    print(coordinate_x, coordinate_y)

Answer (score 0):

Blender's [image object](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.pixels) provides access through the [pixels property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/652/935).

Also note performance isn't great, [copying the pixel array](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3678/935) can help. You may also want to copy to a numpy array, numpy has been included with blender releases for a while now.

Comment: I think rather about fast getting x and y coordinate by mouse click in IMAGE_EDITOR. Instead, write two number user can one click and choose point. Regards.